# How to change font color in bootstrap 2.3.2

Tags: css

Would someone please tell me how to change the font color on bootstrap 2.3.2?  I want all of the typography to be color: #000000;, except for links of course.  Everything I've tried adding to my custom css file hasn't worked.

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked the order in which your css files are loaded ? Usually the problem comes from the fact that your bootstrap files are loaded **after** your custom CSS, thus overriding your custom settings.

Another problem could be your browser cache. Be sure to refresh the css files also (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>  or <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>).

Answer (score 2):

## Overwrite with custom CSS

Create a file, e.g. `custom.css` with this content:

```
body {
    color: #000;
}
```

Then, make sure to include it *after* bootstrap:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="custom.css" type="text/css" />
```

## Generate custom bootstrap.css

You could also compile a custom bootstrap css [here](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) and set `@text-color` to `#000`.

Answer (score 2):

You can change in bootstrap.css

```
  body {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #000000;    // Changed
    }
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: custom.css is loading after bootstrap.

Comment: Sorry about the short reply; hit the wrong key.  Yes, the custom.css is loading after the bootstrap.css. The custom.css has   body {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #000000;    // Changed
    }